# Problem with using capt-of and float packages

Tags: floats, newfloat, capt-of

I was trying to answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/581714 and came up with this MWE using both the `capt-of` and `float` packages. I thought that I had followed the instructions presented for the packages and came up with this.

```
% captionverbprob.tex  SE 581714
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{plain}
\newfloat{Vcode}{tbp}{vcd}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\listof{Vcode}{Verbatims}
\newpage
\lipsum[1]
\begin{verbatim}
Verbatim text bla bla bla bla bla bla
This is verbatim bla bla bla bla bla bla
\end{verbatim}
\captionof{Vcode}{Verbatim stuff}

\begin{Vcode}[b]
\centering
Verbatim text bla bla bla bla bla bla \newline
This is verbatim bla bla bla bla bla bla
\caption{Floating verb stuff}
\end{Vcode}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately when compiling this via `latexpdf` I got the error message:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\@tempf ... \@parboxrestore \normalsize \@fs@capt 
                                                  {\@nameuse {fnum@#1}}{\ign...
l.16 \captionof{Vcode}{Verbatim stuff}
```

But the `Vcode` environment worked and the `\captionof` both got listed in the `\listof{Vcode}{...}` while the `\captionof` did not appear in the body of the document.

I hope that someone can resolve this problem.

Comment: use `caption`  rather than `capt-of` package to define `\captionof`: the latter is a simple (one line) version of `\captionof` that can not cope with float package declarations,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `caption`  rather than `capt-of` package to define `\captionof`: the latter is a simple (one line) version of `\captionof` that can not cope with float package declarations,

If you just switch the package you get the warning

```
Package caption Warning: \captionsetup{type*=...} or \captionof
(caption)                outside box or environment on input line 17.
```

so

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{plain}
\newfloat{Vcode}{tbp}{vcd}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\listof{Vcode}{Verbatims}
\newpage
\lipsum[1]
\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{verbatim}
Verbatim text bla bla bla bla bla bla
This is verbatim bla bla bla bla bla bla
\end{verbatim}
\captionof{Vcode}{Verbatim stuff}
\end{minipage}

\begin{Vcode}[b]
\centering
Verbatim text bla bla bla bla bla bla \newline
This is verbatim bla bla bla bla bla bla

\caption{Floating verb stuff}
\end{Vcode}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```